# Create new branch for existing Gerrit change

Tags: git, gerrit

I accidentally submitted a commit (let's call it *C*) for a feature (*F*) to Gerrit without creating a feature branch for that commit. The change commit was instead located directly on the `develop` branch.

I have subsequently made one more commit on my local master.

**How can I update my Gerrit change so that it is on a feature branch instead of on the `develop` branch?**

I have tried this:

1. Checked out my local commit for feature *F*
2. Created a branch `feature/some_feature` on the commit *C*
3. Amended to commit *C*, but on the new branch (using the same change ID)
4. Pushed the new feature branch to Gerrit

This updates the Gerrit change with the new content (which I can see in the web-interface). But the *Branch* field in the GUI still has the value `develop`. I would like this to change to the name of the feature branch, `feature/some_feature`.

(In my local repo I now have two commits for feature *F*, one on `develop` and one on `feature/some_feature`. This is not a problem if I just get the Gerrit change right.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to change the destination branch of a change. You need to abandon/revert the original change and submit another to the right branch.

First of all: have you submitted (merged) the commit or just pushed (sent to review) it? If the commit *C* is under review use the *Abandon* button to cancel it. If the commit *C* is already merged then use the *Revert* button to revert it.

Finally use the *Cherry Pick* button to apply the same change on the feature branch. Note: the feature branch must be previously created in *Projects > YOUR-PROJECT > Branches* menu.